# jQuery Roadmap - Reload or refresh

Tags: jquery, timeline

I am creating a timeline (https://github.com/stefanomarra/jquery-roadmap), and then reloading WITHOUT page reload, but it does not hold the changed data since page reload when i goto the next view

I have cleared the html container

```
$('#setup_timeline').roadmap(events, {
        eventsPerSlide: 5,
        slide: 1,
        prevArrow: '<i class="icon-arrow-left15"></i>',
        nextArrow: '<i class="icon-arrow-right15"></i>'
    });
```

I call this code each time as the array 'events' gets changed, and its ok, as long as the second slide is not called, then it reverts back to the original state when the page was last refreshed.

Ideas ??

Answer (score 0):

Found out that the element was not being cleared just the array and timeline.

Created the div inside div dynamically and deleted and recreated each time - all worked then.

Code below

```
    $("#setup_timeline").remove();
    jQuery('<div id="setup_timeline"></div>').appendTo('#timeline_panel_collapse_body');
    $('#setup_timeline').roadmap(events, {
        eventsPerSlide: 5,
        slide: 1,
        prevArrow: '<i class="icon-arrow-left15"></i>',
        nextArrow: '<i class="icon-arrow-right15"></i>'
    });
```